# Fluent Linq: Get he contents of Table1 where entry in Table2

Tags: sql, linq

Using the Linq fluent syntax, how do I get the contents of table1 using a foreign key from table 2. For example given tables

```
tblPropertyExtras       tblExtra

PropertyExtraId         ExtraId
propertyId              ExtraName
ExtraId
```

I am trying to do the equivalent of the SQL

```
Select tblExtra.*
From tblPropertyExtras  Inner Join tblExtra 
   On tblPropertyExtras.ExtraId  = tblExtra.ExtraId
Where propertyId = 1234
```

(Extra part :Is there a converter from SQL to Linq that I can use while I am annoyingly bad a Linq?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:-

```
var result = db.tblPropertyExtras.Join(db.tblExtra,
                                       pe => pe.ExtraId,
                                       e => e.ExtraId,
                                       (pe, e) => new { pe, e })
                                 .Where(x => x.pe.propertyId == 1234)
                                 .Select(x => x.e);
```

Although I am not a fan of Method Syntax when it comes to Joins. I prefer query syntax instead:-

```
var result1 = from pe in db.tblPropertyExtras
              join e in db.tblExtra
              on pe.ExtraIdequals e.ExtraId
              where pe.propertyId == 1234
              select e;
```

Comment: I prefer the query syntax too, however where I work has decided to standardise on the other syntax

Comment: I am using the 2nd statement. Code should be easily maintainable, and the 1st piece of code is just horrible. The 2nd one is readable. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

```
var query =
  from p in tblPropertyExtras
  where p.propertyId == 1234
  select p.tblExtras;
```

If the Database has been mapped properly you should just be able to go `Entity.ForeignEntities`.

Fluent Linq is usually in the order of:

```
from
where
order
select
```

Comment: Thanks. Should be == in the where clause

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
var query =(from p in Contex.tblPropertyExtras
            from c in Contex.tblExtra.where(x=>x.ExtraId==p.ExtraId  )
            where p.propertyId == 1234
             select p).ToList();
```